# What is height texture used for?

Tags: godot, fragment-shader

Downloaded texture asset from asset store. But there's a texture called XX_height.png as shown below.

I understand that there is approximately height information, but I don't think this information will actually adjust the height in the vertex shader, and I'm wondering how it's used in the fragment shader.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: heightmap godot

Answer (score 2):

It warps the uv coordinates based on the view to give you an illusion of depth.

Depicted (sorry by the compression artifacts):

[image]

What you see here is an animated GIF of a quad mesh rotating. The Albedo texture is the Godot icon, and the height texture is a checkerboard. *Plus compression artifacts.*

Observe that the parts of the height texture that are black appear to be further back (they have extra parallax) than the parts of the height texture that are white. *You can control how back they appear to be by changing the `heightmap_scale`*. This is, of course, accomplished without moving the vertex.

Since Godot allows us to convert the material to a shader material, we can see the code to get this effect (I have removed not used uniforms and extra spacing):

```
// NOTE: Shader automatically converted from Godot Engine 4.1.dev1's StandardMaterial3D.

shader_type spatial;
render_mode blend_mix,depth_draw_opaque,cull_back,diffuse_burley,specular_schlick_ggx;
uniform vec4 albedo : source_color;
uniform sampler2D texture_albedo : source_color,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform float roughness : hint_range(0,1);
uniform sampler2D texture_metallic : hint_default_white,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform vec4 metallic_texture_channel;
uniform sampler2D texture_roughness : hint_roughness_r,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform float specular;
uniform float metallic;
uniform sampler2D texture_heightmap : hint_default_black,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform float heightmap_scale;
uniform vec2 heightmap_flip;
uniform vec3 uv1_scale;
uniform vec3 uv1_offset;

void vertex() {
    UV=UV*uv1_scale.xy+uv1_offset.xy;
}

void fragment() {
    vec2 base_uv = UV;
    {
        vec3 view_dir = normalize(normalize(-VERTEX)*mat3(TANGENT*heightmap_flip.x,-BINORMAL*heightmap_flip.y,NORMAL));
        float depth = 1.0 - texture(texture_heightmap, base_uv).r;
        vec2 ofs = base_uv - view_dir.xy * depth * heightmap_scale * 0.01;
        base_uv=ofs;
    }
    vec4 albedo_tex = texture(texture_albedo,base_uv);
    ALBEDO = albedo.rgb * albedo_tex.rgb;
    float metallic_tex = dot(texture(texture_metallic,base_uv),metallic_texture_channel);
    METALLIC = metallic_tex * metallic;
    vec4 roughness_texture_channel = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    float roughness_tex = dot(texture(texture_roughness,base_uv),roughness_texture_channel);
    ROUGHNESS = roughness_tex * roughness;
    SPECULAR = specular;
}
```

The documentation on `heightmap_enabled` says:

> If `true`, height mapping is enabled (also called "parallax mapping" or "depth mapping"). See also [`normal_enabled`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basematerial3d.html#class-basematerial3d-property-normal-enabled). Height mapping is a demanding feature on the GPU, so it should only be used on materials where it makes a significant visual difference.

---

If we also enable [`heightmap_deep_parallax`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basematerial3d.html#class-basematerial3d-property-heightmap-enabled) Godot will fill the cliffs of the height... *I don't know how better to express it*.

Depicted (again, sorry for compression artifacts):

[image]

This is the code:

```
// NOTE: Shader automatically converted from Godot Engine 4.1.dev1's StandardMaterial3D.

shader_type spatial;
render_mode blend_mix,depth_draw_opaque,cull_back,diffuse_burley,specular_schlick_ggx;
uniform vec4 albedo : source_color;
uniform sampler2D texture_albedo : source_color,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform float roughness : hint_range(0,1);
uniform sampler2D texture_metallic : hint_default_white,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform vec4 metallic_texture_channel;
uniform sampler2D texture_roughness : hint_roughness_r,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform float specular;
uniform float metallic;
uniform sampler2D texture_heightmap : hint_default_black,filter_linear_mipmap,repeat_enable;
uniform float heightmap_scale;
uniform int heightmap_min_layers;
uniform int heightmap_max_layers;
uniform vec2 heightmap_flip;
uniform vec3 uv1_scale;
uniform vec3 uv1_offset;

void vertex() {
    UV=UV*uv1_scale.xy+uv1_offset.xy;
}

void fragment() {
    vec2 base_uv = UV;
    {
        vec3 view_dir = normalize(normalize(-VERTEX)*mat3(TANGENT*heightmap_flip.x,-BINORMAL*heightmap_flip.y,NORMAL));
        float num_layers = mix(float(heightmap_max_layers),float(heightmap_min_layers), abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), view_dir)));
        float layer_depth = 1.0 / num_layers;
        vec2 P = view_dir.xy * heightmap_scale * 0.01;
        vec2 delta = P / num_layers;
        vec2 ofs = base_uv;
        float depth = 1.0 - texture(texture_heightmap, ofs).r;
        float current_depth = 0.0;
        while(current_depth < depth) {
            ofs -= delta;
            depth = 1.0 - texture(texture_heightmap, ofs).r;
            current_depth += layer_depth;
        }
        vec2 prev_ofs = ofs + delta;
        float after_depth  = depth - current_depth;
        float before_depth = ( 1.0 - texture(texture_heightmap, prev_ofs).r  ) - current_depth + layer_depth;
        float weight = after_depth / (after_depth - before_depth);
        ofs = mix(ofs,prev_ofs,weight);
        base_uv=ofs;
    }
    vec4 albedo_tex = texture(texture_albedo,base_uv);
    ALBEDO = albedo.rgb * albedo_tex.rgb;
    float metallic_tex = dot(texture(texture_metallic,base_uv),metallic_texture_channel);
    METALLIC = metallic_tex * metallic;
    vec4 roughness_texture_channel = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    float roughness_tex = dot(texture(texture_roughness,base_uv),roughness_texture_channel);
    ROUGHNESS = roughness_tex * roughness;
    SPECULAR = specular;
}
```

---

This effect does not interact with the lighting model. But you can combine it with normal and occlusion textures.

---

See also:

- [Normal mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping).
- [Bump mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping).
- [Parallax mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping).